# Unable To Figure out this CSV Split Logic

Tags: c#, csv, logic

I know how to split .CSV files in C# and have a program that does so.
My problem is one with my logic for the next task I am wanting to do.

I have this data

---

```
Name         AddressName       AddressContact  AddressType  Address

Ap Services  Main address      Ap Services A/S1   50        789 E 5300 S
Ap Services  BILLING           Ap Services A/S2   20        123 W 5200 S
Ap Services  Shipping address  Ap Services A/S3   10        456 N 5100 S
```

I have many files in my CSV that are not duplicates, because their fields are different, but they have the same `Name`. I am wanting to simply have the Name only be printed out one time while putting new columns at the end to house the other fields. The columns would have to be new but I figured it'd be easier to put them at the end of the `.length` of the row.

This is what I would like the output CSV file to be formatted to:

---

```
Name         AddressName       AddressContact  AddressType  Address   AddressContact2 AddressType2 Address2  AddressContact3 AddressType3  Address3
 Ap Services Main address      Ap Services A/S1   50        789 E 5300 S   Main address      Ap Services A/S1   50        789 E 5300 S   Main address      Ap Services A/S1   50        789 E 5300 S
```

I am using C# and can not figure out the logic or loop I need to use to do this.
I need to read in the file, split it in that way and then print it out with each customer name showing up only once while putting the info all on 1 line.

Does anyone have any idea how I may achieve this?

### My C# Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String path = "C:\\Desktop\\";
        String file2 = "customerListAll.csv";
        String file3 = "finalCustomerList.csv";
        ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList();
        //ArrayList al3=new ArrayList();
        String[] dataArray1;
        String[] dataArray2;

        Dictionary<String, String> badCustomers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(path + file3);

        TextFieldParser CSVFile2 = new TextFieldParser(path + file2);
        CSVFile2.SetDelimiters(",");
        dataArray2 = CSVFile2.ReadFields();

        int count = 0;
        while (!CSVFile2.EndOfData)
        {
            if (!badCustomers.ContainsKey(dataArray2[0]))
            {
                String record = String.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataArray2.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (dataArray2[i].Contains(","))
                    {
                        string x = "\"" + dataArray2[i] + "\"";
                        record += x;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        record += dataArray2[i];
                    }
                    if (i < dataArray2.Length - 1)
                    {
                        record += ",";
                    }
                }
                count++;
                if (count % 50 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(count);
                }
                output.WriteLine(record);
            }
            dataArray2 = CSVFile2.ReadFields();
        }
        CSVFile2.Close();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: your question doesn't make sense to me!! I don't understand what you are trying to explain? Where is CSV? Did you change CSV to Tab format here for readability? Where is your code?

Comment: @techspider I opened up the CSV in excel to copy and paste it easier because I did not put the columns in the correct order to simplify my question. I want the output CSV file to have each customer with one name but their other info tacked on to the end of the CSV file- so to add their info to nonexistent columns. I am having a hard time explaining because my issue is the logic. I apologize for not being as clear. I am still learning and do not know how to do this the best way.

Comment: This will be hard to answer without knowing how you are storing the data.  Is it in a datatable or an list or string builder.

Comment: @CharlesNRice I understand! Let me post the code I have to better explain

Comment: @CharlesNRice I will say I do not believe the code I have will work. I am trying to modify it or figure out the code I need to do what I am trying to do :/ I am having such a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to achieve this in C#, out of which very basic and simple is as below.

1. Read all CSV files and store them in separate datatable with
   Headers whatever you want.
2. Join these separate table on the basis of your common field
   ('Name' as in your case)
3. Retrieve the desired output from this datatables after
   join.